# android showing multiple launch icon after installed

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-webview, android-manifest

Please I have an android app with more than 3 android activity, everything is working fine till I added on splashScreen activity that will only show once per app installed or data cleared. Now the problem is when I install app I will see two lunch icon on the screen which is not normal. Please can anyone assist me below are my activity and the use of it.

**SplashScreen**: Once app is installed, it contain webview inside.

**SplashScreenOnload**: every time app is lunched, it will show for 500 milliseconds and redirect to `ApplicationMainActivity`, no webview inside.

**ApplicationMainActivity**: this is main app activity, it contain webview.

**UriSchemActivity**: this is for url scheme extraction, no webview.

**PopLoginActivity**: this is for url popup, any external url clicked in `ApplicationMainActivity` will open here, it contain webview

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.shop"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenOnload"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ApplicationMainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".UriSchemActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:scheme="example" />
                <data android:scheme="fs" />
                <data android:host="www. example.com" />
                <data android:host="example.com" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/app/www/" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/app/" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".PopLoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />

        <service android:name=".FcmMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

at many places cause your problem!

You need decide one launcher Activity

Comment: So where should I put it and where not? That why I have listed the use of each activity

Comment: Which activity you want to show when user opens your app? @Peter

Comment: This activity `SplashScreenOnload `

Comment: So remove intent filter in your Splash Activity

Comment: Please what I want to get rid of `SplashScreenOnload ` and use `ApplicationMainActivity ` for the lunching, should I add both `action` inside `SplashScreenOnload ` to `ApplicationMainActivity `?

Comment: I can not get what you are trying to do! Please tell me your flow and I will help you! @Peter

Comment: if you need to show your SplashScreen (I think this is a welcome screen and should be named "WecomeActivity") just once, inside SplashScreenOnload you will check if you will show SplashScreen or ApplicationMainActivity. Use SharePreferences to save a key for checking if this the first time user open your app!